# VIM: How to move between matching tags?

Tags: vim, ide, ctags

I'm a big fan of ctags, but sometimes it is hard to use it.

In case when I have a few declaration of the functions with the same name - "ctrl + ]" throws you to the first occurrence - which is not always what I need.

How can I see the full list of matching tags so I can choose which one to open?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> will show you a list of tags if there is more than one that matches the word under the cursor.

Answer (score 5):

`:ts` shows the tags for the last tag requested, or you can give it an argument to search for a specific tag.

Answer (score 2):

```
:[count]tn[ext][!]  Jump to [count] next matching tag (default 1).  See
            |tag-!| for [!].  {not in Vi}

                            *:tp* *:tprevious*
:[count]tp[revious][!]  Jump to [count] previous matching tag (default 1).
            See |tag-!| for [!].  {not in Vi}
```